# Difference between is_regular and is_regular_file from boost filesystem

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem

I see [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/boost/filesystem/operations.hpp) `boost::filesystem::is_regular` is guarded by `BOOST_FILESYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED`, so I assume it shouldn't be used anymore.

I tested both methods on files and they seem to give the same result, but given that I can't find anywhere the documentation of these methods, what is the actual difference between `boost::filesystem::is_regular` and `boost::filesystem::is_regular_file`? Are they the same thing or the former is more generic (e.g.: regular symlink, etc.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are identical:

```
inline bool is_regular_file(file_status f) BOOST_NOEXCEPT {
  return f.type() == regular_file;
}

inline bool is_regular(file_status f) BOOST_NOEXCEPT {
  return f.type() == regular_file;
}
```

Sources:

- https://github.com/boostorg/filesystem/blob/de527c68623eba5b87aa7442a48bd18d90e1b26d/include/boost/filesystem/operations.hpp#L321
- https://github.com/boostorg/filesystem/blob/de527c68623eba5b87aa7442a48bd18d90e1b26d/include/boost/filesystem/operations.hpp#L332

I suspect that `is_regular()` was deprecated when the [Filesystem TS](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs) decided to call that function `is_regular_file()` instead.